# iOS Transparent ViewController

Tags: ios, modal-dialog, transparent, viewcontroller

I'm trying to create a transparent modal ViewController, which overlays the current ViewController. I set the backgroundcolor to clearcolor but the background is black,
because the other viewcontroller is not shown behind the new viewcontroller. I want a overlay like a UIAlertView.

I googeled a lot, and the only solution i found was to add a subview.
I'm using iOS5.

Comment: Yes, adding a subview seems the only plausible solution.

Comment: Post some code. What have you tried. Why can't you use a UIView with clearColor as subView?

Comment: I could add a subview, but having a single controller would be nicer in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the background color to clear **after** u present the Model View, setting the background as clear and then presenting will not work.

If u want to present the view like the UIAlertView use this-

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation
        animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];

    CATransform3D scale1 = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.5, 0.5, 1);
    CATransform3D scale2 = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.2, 1.2, 1);
    CATransform3D scale3 = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.9, 0.9, 1);
    CATransform3D scale4 = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, 1.0, 1);

    NSArray *frameValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
        [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:scale1],
        [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:scale2],
        [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:scale3],
        [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:scale4],
        nil];
    [animation setValues:frameValues];//Courtesy zoul.fleuron.cz

    NSArray *frameTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5],
        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.9],
        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],
        nil];    
    [animation setKeyTimes:frameTimes];

    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    animation.duration = .2;
    [self.backColor SETCOLOUR HERE];
    [self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"uialertViewPopUP"];
```

U can over ride the `willMoveToSuperView` method with the code given above.

Answer (score 1):

It's doable with something along these lines. We did it based on this post:

http://trongdth.blogspot.com/2011/08/create-overlay-view-in-ios.html